# How to get realpath for virtual paths?

Tags: php, file, path, directory, realpath

if path is `../b` and current directory is `/var/www/a/c`, then realpath would be `/var/www/a/b`

but if `b` doesn't exist, realpath() returns false.

Is it possible to get the same path even if directory doesn't exist yet?

Comment: how can there be a path or a non existent directory ??

Comment: @Dagon It may not yet be created for example.

Comment: add just add **b** to the current path (its just a string?) - i think im confused here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not available as a pre-defined function format like `realpath()`, just because it's impossible to do in a reliable way.

As an example, on MacOS, doing `ls /etc/..`, you'd think that you'd get a directory listing of `/`. The thing is though that `/etc` is a soft link to `/private/etc`, so doing `ls /etc/..` gives you a listing of `/private`.

This could not be calculated in advance if the link did not yet exist, which is why there is no function that can solve it in the general sense without all files/directories already existing.

In other words, you'd most likely have to write your own function to solve your specific problem.